# insert rss data to database with wcf ria services using presentation model

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, wcf-ria-services, presentation-model

i have read many posts but can not find my answer.my question is a little specific.in my silverlight project i want to get weather data like temp,status and date from yahoo weather and save it to my database countiniously by changing from its rss.so iused webclient and its DownloadStringAsync and DownloadStringCompleted for getting data.also i created a presentation model in my server in models folder(beacause i wanted to use it in my service) so in my DownloadStringCompleted event handler i have done something like this:

```
  void xmlclient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender,DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        XNamespace yweather = "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0";
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            XElement x = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
            weatherquery1 =
               from items in x.Descendants("item")

               select new BusinessApplication1.Web.Models.WeatherConditionModel
               {

               PubDate = items.Element(yweather +"condition").Attribute("date").Value,
               Status = items.Element(yweather + "condition").Attribute("text").Value
               };
             }

           }
```

this is in my viewmodel and i tested it all works.i can get data and also can see the result in datagrid or listbox.
inow i want to save data in my database.i want it to be done automatically and not by a button or a command.i want it to read data  always and save it to database in every 5 minutes for example.so i created my service and i create a custom insert which i can shape it myself:

```
 private void MapwcModel(WeatherConditionTable wctable, WeatherConditionModel wcPM)
     {
        wctable.Status = wcPM.Status;
        wctable.PubDate = wcPM.PubDate;
        wctable.WeatherConditionID = wcPM.WeatherConditionID;

     }

    [Insert]
    [Invoke]
    public void InsertWeatherConditionData(WeatherConditionModel WeatherConditionData)
    {
        WeatherConditionTable wc = WeatherConditionContext.WeatherConditionTables.CreateObject();
        MapwcModel(wc, WeatherConditionData);
        wc.Status = WeatherConditionData.Status;
        wc.PubDate = WeatherConditionData.PubDate;
        WeatherConditionContext.WeatherConditionTables.AddObject(wc);
        WeatherConditionContext.SaveChanges();


    }
```

and my get data:

```
        public IQueryable<WeatherConditionModel> GetWeatherConditionData()
           {
         return from p in this.WeatherConditionContext.WeatherConditionTables
               select new WeatherConditionModel
               {
                   WeatherConditionID = p.WeatherConditionID,
                   Status = p.Status,
                   PubDate = p.PubDate,

               };
           }
```

now i do not know how to force it to save data.i wrote this in my iewmodel but did not work:

```
    foreach (BusinessApplication1.Web.Models.WeatherConditionModel el in weatherquery1)

                {
                WeatherConditionDomainContext context = new WeatherConditionDomainContext();
                EntityQuery<BusinessApplication1.Web.Models.WeatherConditionModel> weatherLoadQuery = context.GetWeatherConditionDataQuery();
                context.Load<BusinessApplication1.Web.Models.WeatherConditionModel>(weatherLoadQuery);
                context.SubmitChanges(delegate(SubmitOperation operation)
                {
                    if (operation.HasError)
                    {
                        operation.MarkErrorAsHandled();
                    }
                }, null);
                }
```

i do not know how to force insert method to work.someone please tell me in  where i am wrong?i know there is somewhere.show me the way.
best regards

Comment: You add changes by creating your WeatherConditionDomainContext *(preferably once only... outside the loop!)* and add entries to the context tables. So far your save code does loads and SubmitChanges, but no changes were actually added to the context's tables so nothing gets saved.

Comment: thanks. but first, i did not tell it to save changes in which time interval yet,so i want it to save at least one data for test but database is empty,second,where i add enteries to context tables,you mean in view model?could you show me in code please?third,is my insert in a correct format?thanks

Comment: no one can help?i don`t know what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it .Many thanks to book: Silverlight 4 Unleased-
chapter 13- from the great : Laurent Bugnion .

first,there is no need to use the WeatherConditionModel as a presentation model
(presentation model id used when you need to save data in multiple tables ).it is just a class used as 
holder of my query output.
second,not need to change Insert method in the service at all(because here i want to save data in just one table)
so , just create your service upon your entity model and build it.after build it in this way,
 you can  call your table in your view model( which i could  not,because i changed my service methods(i changed WeatherConditionTable
to WeatherConditionModel(the class!!) manually as you saw).
third,in my foreach loop,i can save my data to my database.
.i have a combobox and a listbox and a button,i select my city 
from combobox,and hit button that uses a command to my GetRss and it does 
the job nicely now.it shows data and saves it to database.
it is my view model code( described part):

```
      internal void GetRssFeed()
          {
            Feed selectedFeed = (Feed)FeedModel.FeedList[FeedModel.SelectedIndex];
            FeedModel.SelectedFeedName = selectedFeed.FeedName;
            WebClient xmlclient = new WebClient();
            xmlclient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(xmlclient_DownloadStringCompleted);
        xmlclient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(selectedFeed.FeedUrl));

    }

    WeatherConditionDomainContext context = new WeatherConditionDomainContext();
    WeatherConditionTable wct = new WeatherConditionTable();
    void xmlclient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        XNamespace yweather = "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0";
        if (e.Error == null)
        {

            XElement x = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
            weatherquery1 =
               from items in x.Descendants("channel")
               let item=items.Element("item")
               select new WeatherConditionModel
               {
                   Temp = Convert.ToInt32(item.Element(yweather + "condition").Attribute("temp").Value),
                   PubDate = item.Element(yweather + "condition").Attribute("date").Value,
                   Status = item.Element(yweather + "condition").Attribute("text").Value,
                   Humidity=Convert.ToInt32(items.Element(yweather + "atmosphere").Attribute("humidity").Value)
               };

            foreach (WeatherConditionModel wc in weatherquery1)
           {

                   wct.Temp = wc.Temp;
                   wct.Status = wc.Status;
                   wct.PubDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
                   wct.Humidity = wc.Humidity;
                   context.WeatherConditionTables.Add(wct);
                   context.SubmitChanges();


           }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
        }
    }
```

thanks for all attention.i hope it helped someone.tell me if anyone have better ideas.
please mark as answer if it helped anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a hard time understanding what you are trying to do, but the pattern for the last step you show should be more like:

```
// Create data context
WeatherConditionDomainContext context = new WeatherConditionDomainContext();

// Load existing entities
EntityQuery<BusinessApplication1.Web.Models.WeatherConditionModel> weatherLoadQuery = context.GetWeatherConditionDataQuery();
context.Load<BusinessApplication1.Web.Models.WeatherConditionModel>(weatherLoadQuery);

// Update or insert new entries
foreach (BusinessApplication1.Web.Models.WeatherConditionModel el in weatherquery1)
{
    // Update existing entries

    // Or, add new entries if they did not exists
}

// Submit all changes (updates & inserts)
context.SubmitChanges(delegate(SubmitOperation operation)
    {
        if (operation.HasError)
        {
            operation.MarkErrorAsHandled();
        }
    }, null);
```

Comment: about this part:   / Update or insert new entries
foreach (BusinessApplication1.Web.Models.WeatherConditionModel el in weatherquery1)
{
    // Update existing entries

    // Or, add new entries if they did not exists
}   how would i do that? how can i do insert here?

Comment: You do an insert by adding objects to the appropriate tables in the data context. This is basic Entity Framework (EF) stuff, not Silverlight specific. Best read up on EF.

Comment: thanks.but in my view model i do not have access to table name or entity.i can not write: Mytable t=new Mytable ();T,Column="something";......context.Mytable .Add(t);context,submitchanges;  in codebehind you can but i want it in mvvm.

Comment: The code above does not have to be in a VM. While it is correct that your VM should only contain *a certain shape of data* and not know where it comes from, the VM is normally populated by code "somewhere" (preferably in a controller IMHO). The code to do the reverse (store any changes) belongs in the same place.